# Using FormBuilder in Angularjs 2 rc4

Tags: angular

I want using FormBuild in my source. My friend(using ng2 rc1) and I was follow this example.

I don't know link on this question.. sorry..

```
<http://plnkr.co/edit/WTu5G9db3p4pKzs0WvW6?p=preview>.

import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'aaa',
    template: `
        <fieldset [formGroup]="data">
            <input type="text" id="" name="" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="data.name">
            <input type="text" id="" name="" formControlName="email" [(ngModel)]="data.email">
        </fieldset>
    `,
    providers: [
    ],
    directives: [ 
    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES
    ]
})

export class AAA {
    private data: any;

    constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder) {
        console.log(Validators.required);
        this.data = this.formbuilder.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'email': ['', Validators, required]
        });
    }
}
```

But only got error my source. error message is this.validators is not a function.
How can I use Validators? I don't know resolved this. problem with rc4 version?

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: how does your `bootstrap()` look like? Do you have `disableDeprecatedForms()
   provideForms()` to load the new forms module or do you use the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix forms stuff from `@angular/common` (old) and `@angular/forms` (new)

If you use

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms()
   provideForms()
])
```

don't import forms stuff from `@angular/common` and if you don't then don't import from `@angular/forms`

Comment: I have a import that. and I don't have a import that. anyway that error is always.

Comment: Thanks! I know what's different /comong and /forms on your answer. But I can't declare my formbuilder.group()..